# Higher Constraint Multiplier for Larger iPhones in Adaptive Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, adaptive-layout

I'm defining a constraint as a multiplier in from the left margin as below:

[image: The Constraint]

This looks fine on the 4 inch iPhone, but on the larger iPhones it is a little off to the left. Is there any way I can account for this? As far as I'm aware none of the size classes are individual to just the larger iPhones.. The background is a solid image by the way. Can't move it or align things to it

[image: Elements on the 4 Inch iPhone] [image: Larger iPhones Display]

Comment: are you trying to align 8 and the background box?

Comment: @YuchenZhong Yes, as it is in the first image

Comment: Have you consider using center alignment then?

Comment: @YuchenZhong the black box is part of a single background image that is not at the centre of the view. Or do you mean align with the centre and move to the left with multipliers?

Comment: Hmm, this is tricky. But could you tell me also what the **Hours Label** is?

Comment: I switched it to a multiplier <1 from the centre line and that has got it alined. Hours Label is the 24 before it, which it actually shouldn't have been aligned to - it should have been the margin anyway so it was wrong before I changed it to the centre line anyway! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was changing all my multiplier constraints to be set from the centre horizontal and vertical. The layout is now correct across all devices!